# Is it possible to read every transaction my node relays?

Tags: bitcoin-cli, tcp

I'd like to add every valid transaction my node receives to my own database.

At the moment, I'm using `getrawmempool` every second to find new transactions, and then getting the data for them using `getrawtransaction`.

However, these bitcoin-cli queries can be slow. So is there a way to "intercept" every valid transaction my node relays without having to use bitcoin-cli? Preferably using PHP?

Comment: You'll probably have to patch bitcoind to log these transactions somewhere in full.  The RPC interface isn't really well designed for "streaming" data like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was advised that an easy way to read everything my node relays would be to *connect to my node* and accept all the messages it relays.

So here's a basic "node" written in PHP.

```
<?php

// --------
// SETTINGS
// --------
$version    = 60002;
$node       = array('85.119.83.25', 8333); // node you want to connect to
$local      = array('127.0.0.1', 8333); // our ip and port

list($node_ip, $node_port) = $node;
list($local_ip, $local_port) = $local;

echo "\nNode\n----\n";
echo 'version: '.$version.PHP_EOL;
echo 'node:    '.implode($node, ':').PHP_EOL;
echo 'local:   '.implode($local, ':').PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;


// ------------------
// 1. VERSION MESSAGE
// ------------------

// General Functions
function fieldsize($field, $bytes = 1) {
    $length = $bytes * 2;
    $result = str_pad($field, $length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return $result;
}

function swapEndian($hex) {
    return implode('', array_reverse(str_split($hex, 2)));
}

function byteSpaces($bytes) { // add spaces between bytes
    $bytes = implode(str_split(strtoupper($bytes), 2), ' ');
    return $bytes;
}

// Version Message Functions 
function timestamp($time) { // convert timestamp to network byte order
    $time = dechex($time);
    $time = fieldsize($time, 8);
    $time = swapEndian($time);
    return byteSpaces($time);
}

function networkaddress($ip, $port = '8333') { // convert ip address to network byte order
    $services = '01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'; // 1 = NODE_NETWORK

    $ipv6_prefix = '00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF';

    $ip = explode('.', $ip);
    $ip = array_map("dechex", $ip);
    $ip = array_map("fieldsize", $ip);
    $ip = array_map("strtoupper", $ip);
    $ip = implode($ip, ' ');

    $port = dechex($port); // for some fucking reason this is big-endian
    $port = byteSpaces($port);

    return "$services $ipv6_prefix $ip $port";
}

function checksum($string) {
    $string = hex2bin($string);
    $hash = hash('sha256', hash('sha256', $string, true));
    $checksum = substr($hash, 0, 8);
    return byteSpaces($checksum);
}


// MAKE MESSAGES

function makeMessage($payload) {

    // Header
    $magicbytes = 'F9 BE B4 D9';
    $command = '76 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 00 00 00 00 00';
    $payload_size = bytespaces(swapEndian(fieldsize(dechex(strlen($payload) / 2), 4)));
    $checksum = checksum($payload);

    $header_array = [
        'magicbytes'    => $magicbytes,
        'command'       => $command,
        'payload_size'  => $payload_size,
        'checksum'      => $checksum,
    ];

    $header = str_replace(' ', '', implode($header_array));
    echo 'Header: '; print_r($header_array);

    return $header.$payload;

}

function makeVersionPayload($version, $node_ip, $node_port, $local_ip, $local_port) {

    // settings
    $services = '01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'; // (1 = NODE_NETORK)
    $user_agent = '00';
    $start_height = 0;

    // prepare
    $version = bytespaces(swapEndian(fieldsize(dechex($version), 4)));
    $timestamp = timestamp(time()); // 73 43 c9 57 00 00 00 00
    $recv = networkaddress($node_ip, $node_port);
    $from = networkaddress($local_ip, $local_port);
    $nonce = bytespaces(swapEndian(fieldsize(dechex(mt_rand()), 8)));
    $start_height = bytespaces(swapEndian(fieldsize(dechex($start_height), 4)));

    $version_array = [ // hexadecimal, network byte order
        'version'       => $version,        // 4 bytes (60002)
        'services'      => $services,       // 8 bytes
        'timestamp'     => $timestamp,      // 8 bytes
        'addr_recv'     => $recv,           // 26 bytes
        'addr_from'     => $from,           // 26 bytes
        'nonce'         => $nonce,          // 8 bytes
        'user_agent'    => $user_agent,     // varint
        'start_height'  => $start_height    // 4 bytes
    ];

    $version_payload = str_replace(' ', '', implode($version_array));
    echo 'Version Payload: '; print_r($version_array);

    return $version_payload;

}


// -----------------
// 2. SOCKET CONNECT
// -----------------

// Print socket error function
function error() {
    $error = socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
    return $error.PHP_EOL;
}


// i. Create Version Message (needs to be sent to node you want to connect to)
echo "Connect\n-------\n";
$payload = makeVersionPayload($version, $node_ip, $node_port, $local_ip, $local_port);
$message = makeMessage($payload);
$message_size = strlen($message) / 2; // the size of the message (in bytes) being sent


// ii. Connect to socket and send version message
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 6); // IPv4, TCP uses this type, TCP protocol
socket_connect($socket, $node_ip, $node_port);
socket_send($socket, hex2bin($message), $message_size, 0); // don't forget to send message in binary


// iii. Keep receiving data (inv messages) from the node we just connected to
echo "\nReceiving packets from $node_ip...\n\n";
while (true) {
    if (socket_recv($socket, $buffer, pow(2,10), MSG_DONTWAIT)) {
        echo bin2hex($buffer)."\n\n";
    }
}



/* Resources
    - https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation
    - https://coinlogic.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/the-bitcoin-protocol-4-network-messages-1-version/
*/
```

Thanks to theymos for the advice.

### How to use:

Just change the IP at the top of the node you want to connect to, and it will start receiving every message it sends back.

*Warning: It's very basic and I've only just got it working, so use with caution. However, it does seem to be working.*

---

**Bonus:** Here's one in Python: [Making peer connection in Python](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48350/making-peer-connection-in-python/48395#48395)